# How to avoid executing database transactions on dirty data?

Tags: database, postgresql, concurrency, relational-database

I am trying to find an architectural approach to handling the following concurrency issue:

Multiple users may submit `database transactions` to the **same subset of a database table** in a relational database simultaneously, each with different transactions. In this scenario each transaction will run in Isolation level Serializable thus ensuring that the transactions are handled as if they occurred one after the other but this does not solve my specific concurrency issue...

Transaction 1 originates from User 1 who has through the Application made a batch of inserts, updates and deletes on a subset of a table.

User 2 may have started editing the data in the Application any time prior to the commit from Transaction 1 and thus is editing `dirty data`. Transaction 2 thus originates from User 2 who has (unknowingly) made a batch of inserts, updates, deletes on a the same subset of the table as User 1 BUT these are likely to overwrite and in some instances overlap with the changes made in Transaction 1. Transaction 2 will not fail based on MVCC but is not sensible to perform.

I need Transaction 2 to fail (ideally not even start) due to the data in the database (after the Transaction 1 commit) not being in the state that it was in when User 2 received his/her initial data to work on.

There must be "standard" architectural patterns to achieve my objective - any pointers in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is read with lock/record locking not sufficient? User 2 cannot read any row which User 1 has locked, even though User 1 hasn't yet updated that row. (Indeed User 1 might not update that row, but it won't be released until User 1 commits.) This could be 'optimistic locking' but now you need a bunch of application code to detect conflicts.

Comment: Might want to take a look at information for [Repeatable Read](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/transaction-iso.html#XACT-REPEATABLE-READ), which describes the isolation level that is also used by `Serializable`.  If i'm following it is at least close to what you want. Also [Locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) clause to `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

> Transaction 2 will not fail based on MVCC

If the transactions are really done in serializable isolation level, then transaction 2 **will** fail if the transaction includes both the original read of the data (since changed), and the attempted changes based on it.  True serializable isolation was implemented way back in PostgreSQL 9.1.